# How can I return a blob (bytestring) from PiCloud to Google Appengine?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, rest, pickle

I'm using the PiCloud REST API to run a background task from the Google Appengine (GAE). My PiCloud function returns a byte string to GAE as follows:

result = numpy.asarray(arr,numpy.float32).tostring()
return pickle.dumps(bz2.compress(result))

This works OK except that, when the string "result" is large (24MB is a typical value) the pickling blows the returned blob up in size to exceed the 32MB limit on GAE URLfetch responses, even with the bz2 compression. I've tried using json.dumps() but it doesn't work. Is there a way to return the blob that doesn't expand it?

Comment: I should have read the REST API documentation more closely. The solution is to publish the PiCloud function with out_encoding = 'raw'

cloud.files.publish(function, 'function', out_encoding = 'raw')

The result is then returned as a string with no JSON header but with 
 
 Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to find a way of breaking it into separate requests. The issue isn't so much PiCloud; it's simply that GAE has its hard limits.

You can use [cloud.files](http://docs.picloud.com/client_basic.html#cloud-files) to store the file on the server. Then retrieve it in chunks.

Comment: Thanks Ken. The 32MB URLFfetch response quota on GAE is OK for me. My problem was how to send binary data and I overlooked the out_encoding keyword for files.publish(), see above.